Python Django urls.py do not remove part of the address
I have urls.py as is. If I go to /catalog/product/"path" then on this page I can't specify a URL that won't include /catalog/product/"path". Please tell me how to change urls.py so that in the html template I can call values ​​different from /catalog/product/"path"
My template


<div class="PD-local">
                    <a href="/">Главная</a>
                    &emsp;&gt;&emsp;
                    <a href="{{ index.category.slug }}">{{ product.category.name }}</a>
                    &emsp;&gt;&emsp;
                    <a href="{{ category.slug }}">{{ product.name }}</a>
                </div>



My urls.py
urlpatterns = [
path('search/', views.catalog, name='search'),
path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.catalog, name='index'),
path('product/<slug:product_slug>/', views.product, name='product'),
path('product/model/<slug:model_slug>', views.model, name='model'),

]

You add a leading slash, so:
<div class="PD-local">
    <a href="/">Главная</a>
    &emsp;&gt;&emsp;
    <a href="/{{ index.category.slug }}">{{ product.category.name }}</a>
    &emsp;&gt;&emsp;
    <a href="/{{ category.slug }}">{{ product.name }}</a>
</div>
But, this is not a good idea. You better use the {% url … %} template tag [Django-doc] to reverse URLs:
<div class="PD-local">
    <a href="/">Главная</a>
    &emsp;&gt;&emsp;
    <a href="{% url 'index' index.category.slug %}">{{ product.category.name }}</a>
    &emsp;&gt;&emsp;
    <a href="{% url 'index' category.slug %}">{{ product.name }}</a>
</div>

Thank you for your participation, but I tried both options, including trying again after your advice, it doesn’t work!

@h1gfun4: what does not work with the second? Typically it raises an error if it can not reverse...

@h1gfun4: I don't think you have to rewrite half the application to introduce a couple of {% url ... %}s, do you have an app_name = ... in the `urls.py by any chance?

In the second case there was such an error, but I understand where it comes from and therefore I do not delve into this moment, otherwise I would have to rewrite half the application.
response = get_response(request)
And something elementary helped me
<a href="/catalog/{{ product.category.slug }}"
But thank you very much, because without this "/" symbol at the beginning of the url it always gave me the meaning of this page))) LIVE AND LEARN) THANKS)
P.S. somehow our proverbs are very poorly translated into transgender language
